# "bq" command line tool throws CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: ssl, google-bigquery, ssl-certificate, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

**Update (2019-02-07): the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117948931) has now been fixed, so if you're still running into this, try `gcloud components update`.**

---

At some point during the past few monthts, my `bq` tool stopped working. Even a simple thing shows this error:

```
$ bq show
BigQuery error in show operation: Cannot contact server. Please try again.
Traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bigquery_client.py", line 685, in BuildApiClient
response_metadata, discovery_document = http.request(discovery_url)
File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/transport.py", line 176, in new_request
redirections, connection_type)
File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/transport.py", line 283, in request
connection_type=connection_type)
File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1626, in request
(response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1368, in _request
(response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1288, in _conn_request
conn.connect()
File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1082, in connect
raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)
```

I've tried the following:

- `sudo gcloud components update` (version 221.0.0).
- `sudo pacman -Syu` (system update) to get the latest set of SSL certificates. This is Arch Linux, so pretty much always bleeding edge.
- `sudo gcloud components reinstall`.
- Uninstalling `google-cloud-sdk`, wiping out remaining `/opt/google-cloud-sdk` and reinstalling entirely from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/google-cloud-sdk).
- Adding `--httplib2_debuglevel=3` (valid values are not documented, found the value `3` [here](https://github.com/salrashid123/gcpsamples)). This does not give any extra output.
- Adding one of `--ca_certificates_file=/etc/ca-certificates/extracted/tls-ca-bundle.pem`, `--ca_certificates_file=/etc/ca-certificates/extracted/ca-bundle.trust.crt` and `--ca_certificates_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` one of which must surely be the bundle of root certificates on my system. The last one of these is used by curl, which can talk to `www.googleapis.com` just fine.
- Poking at the source code to discover that `/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/cacerts.txt` is the cert bundle used by default. If I try this one with `curl --cacert ...`, it still works.
- Setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable in this shell. As expected, this also doesn't make a difference; the SSL error occurs before `bq` has even had a chance to begin the OAuth handshake.
- Adding `--disable_ssl_validation`. This "works" but is obviously not secure.

Anyone else seeing this, or have ideas how to debug/solve?

Comment: I wonder if this is something related to Python OpenSSL itself. If you try to make SSL connections using `requests` to any secured url, does it work? Maybe updating pyopenssl and http2 might change something as well.

Comment: I got same error today, after updating to Ubuntu 18.10, temporarily using --disable_ssl_validation though its not recommended

Comment: Probably it has something to do with new Ubuntu 18.10? Since I also have it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the exact same issue using Arch Linux as well.

When you issue a `bq` command on the command line however, I'm pretty sure that the certificate file at `/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/cacerts.txt` is **not** used, because the flag `--ca_certificates_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` will is put into the flags automatically in the application bootstrap process. On Arch Linux, this file is a symlink to `/etc/ca-certificates/extracted/tls-ca-bundle.pem`.

I've tried using `curl` and `openssl s_client` with this CA bundle against the API URL being called, which is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest
```

and it works just fine.

My assumption is, that this is not an issue with missing or expired certificates. My `pyopenssl` package is at version `18.0.0`, so I'm at the newest version here. However, I think this issue is caused by unsupported ciphers or algorithms in the TLS handshake process.

Comment: Thank you for confirming I'm not crazy. Must be something Arch-related then... somehow. Did you install `google-cloud-sdk` from AUR as well?

Comment: Never mind, I tried from the official tarball and it also fails. I filed an issue with gcloud: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117948931

Answer (score 0):

There's a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35907626) with a similar behavior that you're having. I suggest [starring it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) to keep updated about it as well providing your scenario.

If you're behind a corporate proxy, on comment [#8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35907626#comment8) there's a scenario which the corporate proxy replaces the certificate, and the workaround is provided on comment [#16](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35907626#comment16)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like a different error. And I'm not behind a proxy. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115556782 looks closer to the mark, but is also eventually about proxies.